# How can I implement OutlookApp.Onquit Event with redemption on delphi and Avoid Hung outlook when app is busy

Tags: delphi, outlook, outlook-redemption

I want to prompt a user when outlook is getting closed. I am already using redemption with my application. I dont want to use TOutlookApplication Class which provided with Delphi.

Kindly help me to implement Outlook Onclose/OnQuit event on Delphi.

When I used an object of TOutlookApplication for OnQuit event, if my application is busy for eg: Executing a SQL staement which takes more than 1 min, my outlook gets hangs. Ultimately I need to avoid that hang.

please help me in this.

Thank and Regards,
Vijesh Nair

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I implemented Outlook event listener. I used imported Outlook_tlb library to work with outlook. You can recieve outlook notifications via `IConnectionPoint` interface. Your event listener class has to implement `IDispatch` interface (at least `Invoke` method).
so, there is sample code:
declare TOutlookEventListener as:

```
TOutlookEventListener = class(TInterfacedObject, IDispatch)
  strict private
    FConnectionPoint : IConnectionPoint;
    FCookie : integer;
    function GetTypeInfoCount(out Count: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetTypeInfo(Index, LocaleID: Integer; out TypeInfo): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetIDsOfNames(const IID: TGUID; Names: Pointer;
                         NameCount, LocaleID: Integer; DispIDs: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
    function Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer;
                Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create();
end;
```

in constructor code you have to get instance of OutlookApplication, find connection point and register itself as event listener:

```
constructor TOutlookEventListener.Create();
var cpc : IConnectionPointContainer;
    ol : IDispatch;
begin
    inherited Create();

    ol := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');

    cpc := ol as IConnectionPointContainer;
    cpc.FindConnectionPoint(DIID_ApplicationEvents, FConnectionPoint);
    FConnectionPoint.Advise(self, FCookie);
end;
```

using `Invoke`  method you can filter events. `Quit` event has DispID = 61477

```
function TOutlookEventListener.Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer; Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo,
          ArgErr: Pointer): HResult;
begin
    result := S_OK;

    case DispId of
        61442 : ; // ItemSend(const Item: IDispatch; var Cancel: WordBool);
        61443 : ; // newMailEventAction();
        61444 : ; // Reminder(const Item: IDispatch);
        61445 : ; // OptionsPagesAdd(const Pages: PropertyPages);
        61446 : ; // Startup;
        61447 : begin
            FConnectionPoint.Unadvise(FCookie);
            FConnectionPoint := nil;

            form1.OutlookClosed(self);
        end
        else
            result := E_INVALIDARG;
    end;
end;
```

other methods have to return E_NOTIMPL result.

In the form OnCreate event handler create an instance of TOutlookEventListener (let suppose that outlook is already running). I also used TForm1.OutlookClosed(sender : TObject) event to show notification message.

read this article about outlook events : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4230/Implementing-Outlook-2002-XP-Event-Sinks-in-MFC-C

Comment: seems my answer is not fully correct, because i've just googled what  Redemption is :) but still may be it will be usefull.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. This question has nothing to do with Redemption :-)

Comment: Thanks Teran, I will check your solution and will comeback to you.

Comment: Hi Teran, Thanks its working well. However I have question, when I run a SQL statement, which takes 1 min or more for complete, in my application, The outlook gets hang. Can you help me to avoid that.

Comment: sorry, I have not idea about SQL and outlook